# Unable to use the default PipeDate

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use the default **date pipe** provided by `@angular/common`.

```
{{ publication.createDate | date }}
```

The code below is the *publications.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { PublicationsRoutingModule } from './publications-routing.module';
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';
import { PublicationsComponent } from 'src/app/views/pages/publications/list/publications.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PublicationsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    PublicationsRoutingModule,
    DataTablesModule
  ],
})
export class PublicationsModule { }
```

*app.module.ts:*

```
import { CommonModule, DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './views/pages/login/login.component';
import { AuthInterceptorService } from './interceptors/auth-interceptor.service';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule, // required animations module
    ToastrModule.forRoot(), // ToastrModule added
  ],
  providers: [    
    DatePipe,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptorService,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: []
})
export class AppModule {
 }
```

But this error is shown:

> error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'date'.

Comment: These weird errors usually have something to do with a bugged installation. Try to remove `node_modules` folder, remove `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` again.

Answer (score 3):

Once a module imports `CommonModule`, you don't need to provide it again, unless you are changing the implementation itself for the `DatePipe`. You should consider removing it in the `providers: []` of the module.